# Loading PHP file in html div content is not working

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem while loading PHP file in html div content. It loads fine but not sending data to database. No issue in console.

*Loading formularz.php in div*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Formularz").click(function(){
    $(".container").load('formularz.php');
  });
});
```

Formularz.php file:

```
<?php
        $host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sklep_komputerowy";  
        $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);

        
        if(isset($_POST['save']))
        {
        
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $nazwa = $_POST['nazwa'] ;
        $typ = $_POST['typ'] ;
        $cena = $_POST['cena'] ;
        
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `asortyment` (id,nazwa, typ, cena) VALUES ('$id','$nazwa', '$typ', '$cena') ";
          mysqli_query($conn,$sql)
    or die ("essa");
        }       
        
        ?>

<form method="post">
            ID    <input type="text" name= "id" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' /><br>
            Nazwa <input type="text" name="nazwa"  /><br>
            Typ   <input type="text" name="typ" /><br>
            Cena  <input type="text" name= "cena" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' /><br>
                  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Dodaj"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: I don't see how the JS and the PHP/HTML are related? The JS has an event on an unknown element with id `Formularz`. When it's clicked, all that it's doing is to load a file `formularz.php` with a GET request and store the result in elements with the class `.container`..

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input. It's not only about security, if any of the posted values contains, for example, a `'`, your query will break.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Form tag in html requires prop `action` to make the request using the specified method.
`<form action="/formularz" method="post">`
Also, as we discussed in comments, if you want to redirect to index after the execution, use inside the `if`, right at the end, `header('location: /');`

Comment: What would that solve? And putting `action="/"` it will post the data to `/index.php` in the root. Not having it will make it post to itself.

Comment: you just could give it a try, you don't have to be mean

Comment: I'm not the OP and I know this won't make any difference at all. If you write an answer, you need to be ready to back it up if you get questions about it. It's not me being mean, I'm just asking for the rational behind it. If it's just a guess, then please don't write it as an answer. If you do, it just takes time for the OP to test while many answers like this will make it harder for users to find the correct one.

Comment: action="/" helped, when i submit data it insert it in database but page is loading formularz.php instead staying in index.php, any idea?

Comment: @zirekx try to put the path to this script in "action".

Comment: The actually reason is that the <form> tag requires an action to perform requests using the specified method. So instead expecting the data to be send to the same file when missing "action" you should put "action" using the path to the script

Comment: You guessed right, even though it actually goes against what the OP posted (since they have the PHP and the form in the same file, called `formularz.php` while `/` means the index). I still stand by my first comment/question. What would using the OOP version of mysqli change anything?

Comment: Yes, I did it. <form method="post" action="formularz.php" >, but still it redirects me to formularz.php page after submit

Comment: Nothing, but I had this problem some time ago and changing to OOP helped. And is a good practice to use OOP in PHP, since all frameworks are using OOP PHP. It was a suggestion, not an actually answer, calm down.

Comment: @zirekx hopeing the files are in the same directory if you used it like this.

Comment: @zirekx - _"but still it redirects me to formularz.php page"_ - If you've set the action to `formularz.php`, that is what should happen. It's literally telling the form to submit to that file. We don't know what you want to happen so it's pretty hard for us to know what to change.

Comment: @zirekx, sorry, i missunderstood you. If you want a redirect to index after this use the following line right after 'mysqli_query()'........
"header('location: /');"

Comment: It should be: `header('location: /'); exit;`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i edited my answer, use the code provided by Magnus